# Is there any way to get the source code line number in C code in run time?

Tags: c, runtime-error, line-numbers

Is there any way to get the source code line number in C code in run time? 
The thought behind it is, suppose a software is made in plain C language. the .exe file is distributed to a user who knows nothing about C. Now if there is any error, the user can see the line number and report the error to the manufacturer so that the debugging can be done at manufacturer site. I just to debug the run time errors and get the corresponding line numbers in the source code while running it. I am a beginner in these stuffs.

Comment: Is it not good enough to compile with debug symbols and run code in a debugger like gdb?

Comment: That's a dup that answers your specific question. But as pointed out by the first comment, the better way to debug is to use a debugger.

Comment: I am asking for line numbers during run time. Could you please explain? I am a beginner in coding

Comment: Read the link to the duplicate questions. It explains that. Did you read it?

Comment: the question is edited now.. previously i think i could not explain it properly

Comment: Well, either your program will print an error message which can include the line number as described by the linked answer or the program crashes in which case you get get it to dump a core to be sent back to you for analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gdb instead. But I guess it will work:

```
  if(someThingsWrong())
    printf("wrong at line number %d in file %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the GCC compiler, you can use the Standard Predefined Macro -     `__LINE__`  as a line number placeholder.

The compiler will fill in the line number while compiling.

Eg :-

`printf("%d",__LINE__);`

Comment: The `__LINE__` macro is not specific to GCC.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in macros `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`, which always expand to the current file name and line number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("Error: invalid arguments (%s:%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("You said: %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```